# Misfiring plugs changed but same issue!

Tags: engine, electrical, dodge, idle

2001 dodge durango, over 130,000 miles and normally runs great. Will not idle so plugged code reader in and said two misfired. Changed all plugs and both "boots". Still will start but dies immediately.

Comment: Plug wires? Ignition coil(s)? Distributor? I would start the checking from these.

Comment: Could be catalytic convertor on the way out. A co-worker had the same issue and that was the cause,

Answer (score 0):

The 2001 Durano has Coil on Plug packs. These do go wrong, especially at high mileage. The code you're reading may well be P030x, where x is a number from 1-8, indicating which cylinder is misfiring.

You should check t'internet for your specific engine, but Durango engines have cylinders 1,3,5,7 on the right of the engine, and 2,4,6,8 on the left - assuming you're standing in front of the grill. #1 cylinder is closest to you, on your right.

There are ways to check the COP with a multimeter, but the easiest way is to switch a couple around and see if the error code moves with the coil placement.

As you replaced two 'boots' (? Maybe these are the COPs), it's possible you got the signal cables mixed up. Don't just unplug and reconnect on my guess, though - check that online.